# Is there a way to use "for loop" in the specific range with strings?

Tags: python, file, if-statement, for-loop

Hi stackoverflow Users,

I am wondering how to use for loop with string.

For example,

There is a file (file.txt) like,

=====================

```
Initial Value

    1 2 3
    3 4 5
    5 6 7

Middle Value           <---From Here

    3 5 6
    5 8 8
    6 9 8                  <---To Here

Last Value

    5 8 7
    6 8 7
    5 5 7
```

==================

I want to modify the section of the file only in "Middle Value" and write an output file

after modifying.

I think that if I use "if and for" statements, that might be solved.

I have thought a code like

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:

       for line in f:
           sp1 = line.split()
           line = " ".join(sp1) + '\n'
           if line == 'Middle':
              "Do something until line == 'Last'"
```

I am stuck with `"Do something until line == 'Last'"` part.

Any comments are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you stating that the file always has a line that reads Middle Value?

Comment: You've almost answered your own question, try using a `while` loop

Comment: @AM_Hawk: How is a while loop going to help here?

Comment: @abarnert: while middle == true perform your operations then break

Comment: @AM_Hawk: But inside that `while` loop, you're not iterating the outer `for` loop, so that's just an infinite loop around the same line, which doesn't seem very useful. You'd have to rewrite your code to do the file iterating explicitly (whether with `next`, `readline`, etc.) instead of just looping over it, which is hardly going to simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just code the process as a simple FSM (a [Finite-State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) or more specifically an [event-driven Finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_finite-state_machine)):

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
    state = 1
    for line in f:
        if line == 'Middle Value\n':
            state = 2
            continue  # unless there's something to do upon entering the state
        elif line == 'Last Value\n':  # might want to just test for blank line `\n'
            state = 3
            continue  # unless there's something to do upon entering the state

        # otherwise process to line based on the current value of "state"
        if state == 1:      # before 'Middle Value' has been seen
            pass
        elif state == 2:    # after 'Middle Value' has been seen
            pass
        else:               # after 'Last Value' (or a blank line after 
            pass            # 'Middle Value') has been seen
```

Just replace the `pass` statements with whatever is appropriate to do at that point of reading the input file.

Comment: When I use this code, it works except for one thing. "continue" statement will delete 'Middle Value' and 'Last Value' strings in output file. How does two words remain after modifying?

Comment: `continue` means all further processing in that iteration of the loop will be skipped, including the `if state ==` checks. Either remove it completely to let the latter happen or leave it in and do whatever needs to be done before the statement.

Answer (score 3):

There are three basic approaches.

---

The first is to use a state machine. You could build a real state machine, but in this case the states and transitions are so trivial that it's simpler to fake it by just using a flag:

```
state = 0
for line in f:
    sp1 = line.split()
    line = " ".join(sp1) + '\n'
    if state == 0:
        if line == 'Middle\n':
            state = 1
    elif state == 1:
        if line == 'Last\n':
            state = 2
        else:
            # Thing you do until line == 'Last\n'
    else:
        # nothing to do after Last, so you could leave it out
```

Note that I checked for `'Middle\n'`, not `'Middle'`. If you look at the way you build `line` above, there's no way it could match the latter, because you always add `'\n'`. But also note than in your sample data, the line is `'Middle Value\n'`, not `'Middle'`, so if that's true in your real data, you have to deal with that here. Whether that's `line == 'Middle Value\n'`, `line.startswith('Middle')`, or something else depends on your actual data, which only you know about.

---

Alternatively, you can just break it into loops:

```
for line in f:
    sp1 = line.split()
    line = " ".join(sp1) + '\n'
    if line == 'Middle\n':
        break
for line in f:
    sp1 = line.split()
    line = " ".join(sp1) + '\n'
    if line == 'Last\n':
        break
    else:
        # Thing you do until line == 'Last\n'
for line in f:
    # Nothing to do here, so you could leave the loop out
```

There are variations on this one as well. For example:

```
lines = (" ".join(line.split()) + '\n' for line in f)
lines = dropwhile(lambda line: line != 'Middle', lines)
middle = takewhile(lambda line: line != 'End', lines)
for line in middle:
    # Thing you want to do
```

---

Finally, you can split up the file *before* turning it into lines, instead of after. This is harder to do iteratively, so let's just read the whole file into memory to show the idea:

```
contents = f.read()
_, _, rest = contents.partition('\nMiddle\n')
middle, _, _ = rest.partition('\nEnd')
for line in middle.splitlines():
    # Thing you want to do
```

If reading the whole file into memory wastes too much space or takes too long before you get going, [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) is your friend.

Comment: breaking it into loops is a nice idea

Comment: @Stephan: I think what really makes this readable is the second step. Whether you use a flag, multiple loops repeating the same contents, or code that treats the file as a stream of chars instead of lines, it's going to be ugly (unless you ignore the big file problem, as I did in my last example). But any of the three can be easily abstracted with a state machine, an iterator pipeline, or a simple split over `mmap`, respectively, and then they all become readable.

Comment: yep, i didn't even bother analyzing your last ones because simpler solutions exist, nevertheless there are a lot of good ideas in this thread and not very many upvotes, this community is stingy with their approval clicks.

Comment: @Stephan: Yeah, for really simple cases it often isn't worth thinking them through to the next step. It depends on the situation—are you 2 days from a deadline and slipping it will reduce the value of your stock options by $1M, or are you teaching yourself about a new area of Python or a new application area for fun? (Of course in reality, you're probably somewhere between, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me as I access files a bit differently

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    file_string = f.read()

middle_to_end = file_string.split('Middle Value\n')[-1]
just_middle   = middle_to_end.split('Last Value\n')[0]

middle_lines = just_middle.splitlines()
for line in middle_lines:
    do_something
```

Comment: There is no `list.split` method.

Comment: Thanks - I was paying attention to something else

Comment: `just_middle.split()` splits on any whitespace, not just newlines, so you're going to have lines like `'3'`, `5'`, etc., instead of lines like `'  3 5 6'`. I assume you meant `splitlines`, so I fixed it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think I'd use `partition` rather than `split` here, because of what it does with the error/edge cases… but really, the OP should figure out what he wants to happen with the error/edge cases, then see what they each do (possibly also passing 1 to `split`), then pick the one that does what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if line == 'Middle':` you could flip a boolean flag that allows you to enter another `if inMiddle and line !=`last` statement where you can then modify your numbers

You can replace your for loop with this.

```
inMiddle = false
for line in f:
    sp1 = line.split()
    line = "".join(sp1) + '\n'

    if line == 'Middle':
        inMiddle = true

    if inMiddle and line != 'Last':
        #MODIFY YOUR NUMBERS HERE
    elif line == 'Last':
        inMiddle = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are setting a flag to say you are 'in' the section'.  Below I optionally set a different flag when finished.  You could bail out when flag is 2 for example.

```
with open('file.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:

   section = 0;

   for line in f:
      if line.startswith("Middle"):
          section = 1
      elif line.startswith("Last"):
          section = 2



      if section == 1:
        #collect digits and output to other file     
        f2.write(line)         

      elif section == 2:
         #close file and break out
         f.close()
         f2.close()
         break
      else:
          continue
```

Comment: Why would you ever write `if len(line) > 6 and line[:6] == "Middle"`? First, you don't need the first part, because `line[:6] == "Middle"` will just always be false for anything shorter. Second, `line.startswith("Middle")` is more readable and more robust—not having to count the length of the string yourself means no chance of bugs because you counted wrong, or later changed one but not the other.